# Changing Controls from anywhere

Tags: c#, button, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

What I want to do:

I want do change a background color of a button from anywhere in my code (other classes Xamarin Forms). For example a button A in Page A changes the color of button B in Page B

on Windows you can use the [MethodInvoker Delegat](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker?view=net-5.0) which isn't available on Android/iOS.
Can you give me a hint?

I tried it with the text of the buttons before with the MVVM approach.

in my PageB.xaml:

```
<Button Name="Button_B" Text="{Binding MyText}"/>
```

in my PageB.cs in public PageB

```
BindingContext = new MVVMPageB();
```

in my MVVMPageB.cs

```
private string myText;
public string MyText
{ 
get => mytring;
set
{
mystring = value;
PropertyChanged?
.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(MyText)));
}
```

if i call:

```
MyText("Test");
```

in my MVVMPageB.cs it works fine. but i dont know how to access this from anywhere else.
i tried:

```
var Testobjekt = new MVVMPageB() //pretty sure thats not correct
Testobjekt.MyText("Test"); //wont work
```

Comment: This sounds like a horrible design to have controls on different pages directly interact with each other's UI.  Look at MessagingCenter as a way to pass messages between disconnected pages

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve i tried it the mvvm approach but i couldnt  find a way to Call the Funktions. i tried sonehing with a string like XML <Button text  "{Bindung Mytext}" />  MVVM.cs String mytext Public string Mytext get set etc.       Conclusion. frim m PageB.cs i can call Mytext("test") and the Button text changes. but how can i achieve that from PageB.cs?

Comment: Ok i need 30min im not a the PC rn

Comment: Its  a contentpage where i can get via Shell Tabbar  if this is a usefull info.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve i posted my MVVM approach. sorry i dont understand your comments correctly. i dont know if its to much to ask for but could you correct my approach from above? (if its not completly wrong of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Technique 1**

This is a Singleton pattern for MVVMPageB.

This works if you never have **two** "Page B"s. **IF** there is a Page B on the navigation stack (so you can "Go Back" to it), and you display ANOTHER Page B, **THEN** this will not work well, because both Page B's will refer to the SAME MVVMPageB instance.

```
public class MVVMPageB : ...
{
    // "Singleton": This is the only instance of MVVMPageB.
    private static MVVMPageB _It;
    public static MVVMPageB It
    {
        if (_It == null)
            _It = new MVVMPageB();
        return _It;
    }

    // Your constructor.
    // It is private; only used via "It" getter above.
    private MVVMPageB()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Code in another class, to access a member of the MVVMPageB.

```
MVVMPageB.It.MyText("Test");
```

Replace this code:

```
BindingContext = new MVVMPageB();
```

With this code:

```
BindingContext = MVVMPageB.It;
```

NOTE: Because `MVVMPageB.It` is static, if you go to Page B a second time, it will show the values you had last time (within the same app session).

---

**Technique 2**

A more robust approach, which works even if you create another Page B, requires having some way to pass the current instance of MVVMPageB to MVVMPageA or to PageA.

A complete example depends on exactly how/where you create each page. But this shows the idea.

```
public class MVVMPageB : ...
{
    // Your constructor. Add parameters as needed.
    public MVVMPageB()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public partial class PageB : ...
{
    // Convenience property - our BindingContext is type MVVMPageB.
    public MVVMPageB VMb => (MVVMPageB)BindingContext;
    ...
}

public class MVVMPageA : ...
{
    // This is here, so both MVVMPageA and PageA can find it.
    public MVVMPageB VMb;
}

public partial class PageA : ...
{
    // Convenience property - our BindingContext is type MVVMPageA.
    public MVVMPageA VMa => (MVVMPageA)BindingContext;
    ...
}
```

Code that creates Page B and then Page A:

```
var pageB = new PageB();
var pageA = new PageA();
// Tell MVVMPageA about MVVMPageB.
pageA.VMa.VMb = pageB.VMb;
```

Methods in MVVMPageA can now access members of MVVMPageB:

```
VMb.MyText("Test");
```

Methods in PageA can now access members of MVVMPageB:

```
VMa.VMb.MyText("Test");
```

NOTE: In this dynamic technique, if you go to Page B a second time (in the same app session), it will have a new instance of MVVMPageB.

Comment: I cant Thank you enough for that!! i tried your second technique and its a total win!!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

You need a singleton viewModel for this use. I usually use one for the navbar.
So every scoped page viewModel references the singleton global viewModel inside:

PageAViewModel has property NavBarModel
PageBViewModel has property NavBarModel
and so on..

So it's obvious your button will be bind as
`BackgroundColor={Binding NavBarModel.ActionColor}` on every different page.

Now to have a singleton and obtain its reference i can see two ways: dependency injection (DI) or single instance creation. You can read a lot about DI on the net, while for a simple case you can have a single instance model with a prop like:

```
private NavBarModel _current;
public NavBarModel Current
{
    get
    {
        if (_current == null)
            _current = new NavBarModel();
        return _current;
    }
}
```

then in pages viewModels constructor set `NavBarModel = NavBarModel.Current;`

You would need DI though to reference more models inside your singleton, or/and make your code more reusable. Good luck.

Comment: While you were writing this I submitted a more detailed answer, tailored to OP's situation. If you have a chance, please look over my answer, make any suggestions as you please.